# Python Regex Search And Replace

Tags: python, regex, string, markdown

I'm not new to Python but a complete newbie with regular expressions (on my to do list)

I am trying to use python re to convert a string such as

```
[Hollywood Holt](http://www.hollywoodholt.com)
```

to

```
<a href="http://www.hollywoodholt.com">Hollywood Holt</a>
```

and a string like

```
*Hello world*
```

to

```
<strong>Hello world</strong>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why are you bothering to use a regex?  Your content is Markdown, why not simply take the string and run it through the markdown module?

First, make sure Markdown is installed.  It has a dependancy on ElementTree so easy_install the two of them as follows.  If you're running Windows, you can use the [Windows installer](http://pypi.python.org/packages/any/M/Markdown/Markdown-2.0.win32.exe) instead.

```
easy_install ElementTree
easy_install Markdown
```

To use the Markdown module and convert your string to html simply do the following (tripple quotes are used for literal strings):

```
import markdown
markdown_text = """[Hollywood Holt](http://www.hollywoodholt.com)"""
html = markdown.markdown(markdown_text)
```